# rails 5 method not allowed test environment capybara

Tags: capybara, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following capybara feature scenario:

```
scenario 'user can create an account' do
  visit new_user_path
  within(:css, "form[action='/users']") do
    fill_in 'user[username]', with: 'dummy'
    fill_in 'user[email]', with: 'dummy@email.com'
    fill_in 'user[password]', with: 'password'
    fill_in 'user[password_confirmation]', with: 'password'
    fill_in 'user[address]', with: 'brasilia'
    find("input[type='submit']").click
  end
  expect(page).to have_current_path(root_path)
end
```

When I execute it, I get the following error:

```
1) CreateAccount user can create an account
 Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_current_path(root_path)
   expected "/users" to equal "/"
 # ./spec/features/create_account_spec.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

So I tested in development environment with the same params, and everything is working. I used `save_and_open_screenshot` inside the scenario and I get this message:

```
Method not Allowed
```

I don't know what's is happening. Thanks in advance for any help!

### Edit 1

I inspect the log but I didn't able to see any request being made, but only an error related to database. Here what I found:

```
SELECT schemaname || '.' || tablename
            FROM pg_tables
            WHERE
              tablename !~ '_prt_' AND
              tablename <> 'schema_migrations' AND
              schemaname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
```

I don't know if this will help but the only log snippet thats looks like an error.

### Edit 2

I runned `rails s -e test` and discovered that the hidden_tag authencity token is missing inside the form tag that mades the request. Can this be the cause of `method not allowed`?

Comment: Are you sure you got "Method not Allowed" and not a NotSupportedByDriverError ?  Show the full error message you get.

Comment: Yes, I'm. I searched for `NotSupportedByDriverError ` inside log and `Method not Allowed` is only message that I got. I uploaded this [image](http://imgur.com/a/nUeqY)

Comment: Ok -- "Method not Allowed" is probably a 405 response code -- look in your test.log and see what request is being made.

Comment: I edited the question with what I found in test.log